# Colocar função Javascript dentro do onclick

Tags: javascript, html, funções, javascript-eventos

Então é uma duvida meio boba mais estou precisando muito...
tem como eu colocar uma função Javascript dentro de um buttom 
nesse exemplo abaixo ele chama a função loadDoc(). mais eu gostaria de colocar a função direto dentro do onclick.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="demo">
<h1>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h1>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>
</div>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Fonte: http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FAK6YYP9UBMF

Comment: Colocar tudo isto dentro de um unico botão seria quase que obstruir o HTML sem necessidade, seria melhor colocar o loadDoc dentro de um arquivo com a extensão .js

Comment: eu sei é que eu estou tentando implementar uma taghelper em c# vai ficar tudo via code behind, e a principio vou tentar dessa forma mesmo

Comment: Melhor você editar a pergunta, porque ae muda todo o sentido. Se não as pessoas respondem uma coisa e você quer outra. De detalhes por favor.

Comment: a pergunta esta correta eu quero saber aquilo la mesmo

Comment: Não ficou claro para você ?

Comment: Tá bem vou formular uma resposta.

Comment: a parti do momento que eu olhar um exemplo colocando toda a função dentro do onclick o restante eu dou conta de fazer, mais nao vai ficar dessa forma nao, so quero ver um exemplo para eu poder fazer a taghelper. Obrigado :)

Comment: Independente do taghelper depois do html gerado você pode fazer toda interação no arquivo .js pelo controle de DOM. Fazer tudo inline pode ser um problema.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Usando função anônima

```html
<input type="button" value="anonymous function" onclick="(function(){
console.log('ok');
console.log('ok2');
})()">
```

Nesse snippet apenas quis mostrar que é possível aplicar quebras de linha, tornando o código mais legível.

## Implementando para o seu caso específico:

```
<input type="button" value="anonymous function" onclick="(function(){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
    xhttp.send();
    })()">
```

## Para o caso de enviar parâmetros para a função

No seu caso não há passagem de parâmetros. Caso queira passar parâmetros para a função, veja esse exemplo

```html
<input type="button" value="anonymous function" onclick="(function(v){
console.log(v);
console.log('ok2');
})('ok')">
```

## Observações

Obviamente, qualquer desenvolvedor web que entende o básico é ciente sobre boas  práticas e semântica, no entanto, podem ocorrer situações onde não há como seguir uma semântica correta ou mesmo tais questões ficam fora de contexto. Não cabe aqui julgar se o que pretende fazer é correto ou não pois não é explícito o modelo de negócio, os motivos, razões ou circunstâncias.

Comment: cara perfeito exatamente o que estava procurando vlw

Answer (score 5):

Não tem porque colocar todo um script dentro de um único botão

- *É possível?* A resposta é *sim*
- *É recomendado?* A resposta é *não*

Vou explicar depois o porque não é recomendado.

### Exemplo inline

Mesmo não sendo recomendado vou dar um exemplo, para resolver você precisa trocar as aspas por "aspas simples" (apóstrofos):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="demo">
<h1>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h1>
<button type="button" onclick="var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) { document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = this.responseText; } }; xhttp.open('GET', 'ajax_info.txt', true); xhttp.send();">Change Content</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

> Note que a página http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FAK6YYP9UBMF não está funcionando devido a um bloqueio de segurança do navegador, é falha do w3schools.com mesmo e não do script.

### O que é preferível

O melhor é mover todo script para dentro de um arquivo `.js`, independente de modelo, circunstancias; de qualquer forma é possivel evitar tudo isso usando [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) e ninguém está julgando, isto é uma orientação de como evitar problemas e mostrar que muita coisa é possivel.

Usar tudo em arquivos `.js` vai lhe trazer vantagens como:

- Cache dos recursos
- Reaproveitamento de código
- Diminuição o HTML
- Evitar obstruir o HTML
- Facilita organizar

Um exemplo, crie um arquivo chamado `app.js` e coloque este conteudo:

```
function ready(callback)
{
    if (/^(interactive|complete)$/i.test(doc.readyState)) {
        callback();
    } else {
        doc.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', callback);
    }
}

function loadDoc(url, callback, error)
{
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        callback(this.responseText);
    } else if (error) {
        error(this.status);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();
}

//Equivale ao $.ready do jQuery
ready(function() {
    var botao1 = document.getElementById("botao1");
    var botao2 = document.getElementById("botao2");

    botao1.onclick = function() {
        loadDoc("ajax_info1.txt", function(resposta) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = resposta;
        });
    };

    botao2.onclick = function() {
        loadDoc("ajax_info2.txt", function(resposta) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = resposta;
        });
    };
});
```

E o html deve ficar assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exemplo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
      <div id="demo"></div>

      <button id="botao1">Testar 1</button>
      <button id="botao2">Testar 2</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Veja fica bem menos poluído

Comment: entao eu tentei tbm dessa forma mais nao da certo de uma olhada
http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FAK7UG7C6S75

Comment: @WarlesonReis eu editei a resposta, tenta isso https://jsfiddle.net/vb4psohm/